# Proxies in ionic.config.json is not working ionic v5. CORS Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

[image]I am trying to migrate my application from ionic v3 to ionic v5.

I had ionic.config.json file for proxies which was working fine in ionic v3 but not in v5.

My ionic.config.json file

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/oauth/token",
      "proxyUrl": "https://abc.xyz.us/oauth/token"
    },
    {
      "path": "/v2",
      "proxyUrl": "https://abc.xyz.us/v2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Command

Browser - `ionic serve`
Emulator - `ionic cordova run android -l --external`

I am unable to test my application in the android/ios emulator.

I have gone through many posts but no luck.
Ionic documentation is also not helpful.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

create "network_security_config.xml" and added in resource->android->xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

add below code in config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

Comment: After doing the above configuration, when I try to run "ionic cordova run android -l -external" command, it opens the emulator but I am getting CORS Issue. I know CORS enables in the server because it's working with proxy.config.json.